# Having trouble with process.start

Tags: c#, .net

I want to start process with arguments but it throws me an error

> no file in directory found
> heres code:

```
Process.Start(@"inject.exe example.dll example_process")
```

This is a bit modified code just for "showcase"
first argument is a DLL  and second one is process name
basically whole code "works" (I mean it doesn't throw errors in visual studio) but also doesn't work as it throws exception with message `file not found` or something like that

Comment: Please include the exception information, this exception can easily be thrown from the process start or from the `inject.exe` itself. In both cases, using a fully qualified file path should avoid the issue.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Replace `"inject.exe"` with the `C:\Path\To\inject.exe`.
If the "C:\Path\To\inject.exe" file is not located in the specified directory, you may encounter a "`file not found`" exception in `ex.Message`.
Also, the arguments must have the correct format for `inject.exe`.

```
string exePath = @"C:\Path\To\inject.exe";
string arguments = "example.dll example_process";

try
{
    Process.Start(exePath, arguments);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   //Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); if console application
   String Err=ex.Message;  
}
```

Comment: PSA: Please do not ever suppress exception like this without including a comment justifying why _ALL_  exceptions can be safely ignored here. For new developers at home, this is an example of what NOT to do. If you are not handling the exception, then please do not catch it at all.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller The type of project is not known. For example, I wanted to write the error text in the console, but it is not clear that the project type is console application

Comment: Catchall and suppressing has nothing to do with being a console app or not, empty exception handlers are the bane of software engineers world wide, your example is further polluting the minds of juniors who will see this, see a green tick and think it is a good way to write code.

Comment: absolutely I down voted it ;) You provided a code only answer with little or no explanation and you have included a useless try-catch block, just remove that because it adds a whole new layer of assumptions that do not help OP.

Comment: The solution is using the `, arguments` overload, but the hardcoded path and omnomnom exception handler make this an extremely bad answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster ok. see examples in this link: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-7.0][1]


  [1]: https://process.start

Comment: @Hossein example code usually is not production-ready code. Especially not the 20-year old .NET Framework 1 example code.

Comment: @CodeCaster OK. There is no point in arguing. You are right... :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `inject.exe` is not in the executable folder. If you are not providing the fully qualified path to the *process* that you want to execute, then the path is assumed to be relative to the working folder of the current executable.

You can work around this by including the folder path that `inject.exe` is located in, in the `PATH` environment variable.

You can debug this by checking for the existence of the file first:

```
string processPath = "inject.exe";
Console.WriteLine("File: {0} Exists: {1}",
    System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(processPath),
    System.IO.File.Exists(processPath)
);
```

Parameterizing your process path will help debugging:

```
string processPath = "C:\CoolFolder\inject.exe";
if (System.IO.File.Exists(processPath))
    Process.Start(@"{processPath} example.dll example_process");
else
    throw new ApplicationException(@"Inject not found: {processPath}");
```

Comment: do you think that it will work when im gonna change inject.exe directory to for example C:\CoolFolder\inject.exe

Comment: and then just use C:\CoolFolder\inject.exe instead of inject.exe

Comment: Yes, using a full path should help, but we can only speculate, what if `inject.exe` is throwing the exception? You haven't included a full stack trace so we can only assume at this stage.